# How to I combine the output of 2 print statements to a single line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code

```
import sys

n=int(sys.argv[1])

first = 0
nexter = 0
second = 1

print(first,second)


for i in range(0,n-2):
    nexter = first+second
    print(nexter,end=" ")
    first=second
    second=nexter
```

The output is am getting is

```
0 1
1 2 3
```

However, the output I want is

```
0 1 1 2 3
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Your code suggests you already know how to suppress a newline when printing in Python, so why not do that in *both* places you're printing?

Comment: How do I combine the outputs of 2 print statements in a single line?

Comment: The same way you're already doing it in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already combine multiple prints at `print(nexter,end=" ")`. It means end the print with  a space. You do the same as `print(first,second ,end=" ")`. Complete code :

```
import sys

n=int(sys.argv[1])

first = 0
nexter = 0
second = 1

# Only make this change of ending the print with " ". The default is a new line character.
print(first,second ,end=" ")


for i in range(0,n-2):
    nexter = first+second
    print(nexter ,end=" ")
    first=second
    second=nexter
```

Comment: @KanishkJain, accept the ans, if it solved your issue.